# Typescript 1.8 - ES2015 imports in js files

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, typescript1.8

I would like to start using Typescript on an Existing Babel project. My goal is to be able to add typescript to the build process with as less modifications as possible on the existing code. For this reason, I decided to chain typescript(targeting ES2015) and Babel.
With ts1.8's js files support, I Thought I would finally be able to keep everything as is and then convert files one by one.
But here is the first issue I encountered:
`error TS8003: 'export=' can only be used in a .ts file.`

Typescript doesn't seams to allow es2015 exports syntax:
`export default 'foo';`.
We are using es2015 syntax for imports/exports and I don't want to change it for the old commonJS symtax. Is there any way to make typescript allow it?

**Here is a minimal example demonstrating the issue:**

*hello.js*

```
export default (name) => console.log(`Hello ${name}`);
```

*tsconfig.json*

```
{
    "version": "1.8",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "es2015",
        "allowJs": true,
        "target": "es2015"
    }
}
```

*command line (using typescript 1.8)*

`tsc --outDir ../out`

*result*

`hello.js(1,1): error TS8003: 'export=' can only be used in a .ts file.`

Comment: Seems there is a bit of confusion. `export default 'foo';` is for exporting.

Then you have to import with the related syntax: `import foo from "./jsfile";`

Comment: Anyway look here for example syntax https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2242

Comment: sure, I'm aware of it. I'll edit my question to avoid confusion

Comment: Last time I checked I was sure typescript allowed ES6 modules syntax. I installed typescript@next from npm, but the last version should work too.
What error does it give you exactly?

Comment: the one im my question: `error TS8003: 'export=' can only be used in a .ts file.`

Comment: Read carefully. It says `export= isn't allowed` which means there is another file still using the commonJS syntax. This is not saying you cannot use the ES6 syntax

Comment: Also are you sure you have to chain Typescript and Babel? Typescript already converts its code from ES6 to ES5. There should be no need to chain them. Also check the config of typescript, which module syntax is the target output (UMD, AMD, CommonJS, ...)

Comment: For some reason it displays that `export=` error for this code in a js file: `function MyFunction() {} export default MyFunction`, but not for `export default function MyFunction() {}`.

Comment: @Zorgatone I edited my question to add and exemple. And yes I need Babel. At least for now. This is a bit project making heavy use of Babel polyfills and typescript does not yet support everything that we use.

Comment: Try to change `"module": "commonjs"` to `"module": "es2015"`

Comment: Then be sure to be using ES6 and not CommonJS in `hello.js`

Comment: @Zorgatone with the example of my question, I get the same result

Comment: @TomEsterez Are you sure? The first with commonjs outputted in commonjs syntax (ie. exports =) without errors. I changed it to es2015 and ouputted es2015 without errors (ie. export default...)

Comment: hummm, you've generated `export default` but what was your input? My goal is to keep `export default` in my original js files.

Comment: I copied the same command you used. I just changed the tsconfig.json from `"module": "commonjs"` to `"module": "es2015"`. I wasn't getting any error like that you said. Just the code was outputted as CommonJS instead of ES2015.

Are you sure your error is generated by TypeScript and not BabelJS?

Comment: Oh you know what? You named it hello.js instead of hello.ts

Comment: @Zorgatone the whole point of Tom's question is that the has a lot of .js files that he doesn't want to change. He's using the new `allowJs` flag.

Comment: Oh I thought he didn't want to change the ES6 exports to CommonJS-like TS (i.e. Exports=). Then why would you want to compile this with tsc? I don't get it

Comment: @Zorgatone read about it [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#including-js-files-with---allowjs). Also, using a default export (`export default`) will also produce the `export =` error. He wants to still output es6 modules—not commonjs.

Comment: That's why I suggested to change the output from commonjs to es6z anyway I didn't know that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're getting for the `default export` is [a bug in the TypeScript compiler](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6794). I've sent out [a fix](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6797) since you filed this issue.

If you want to specify the root module in JavaScript files (which is non-standard and specific to certain module loaders like CommonJS), the way to do this is the same way you'd do this in JavaScript:

```
module.exports = yourRootExportObjectHere;
```

The compiler should recognize and respect these as equivalent to `export =` declarations.

Comment: Ok so, I get the wrong error but should I get an error ? Finally am I allowd to write `export default` in a .js files ?

Comment: No, you should not get an error with that default export.. The fix went in, so try the nightly build tomorrow with `npm install -g typescript@next`.

Comment: I'll test it tomorrow then. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've given the nightlies a try and it seems to work. Can you confirm?