# Using TypeScript and Browserify how do I import and use classes more simply

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, browserify

In this example I have 2 files. A controller and a model class.

I want to import the model class in my controller and use it.

So in my controller I want to be able to do:

```
import carModel = require('../models/CarModel.ts');
var newCar:car = new car(1, "red");
```

My model file:

```
export class Car{
    constructor(
        public id: number,
        public color: string
    ){ }
}
```

I can make it work by doing this in my controller:

```
import carModel = require('../models/CarModel.ts');
var newCar:carModel.car = new carModel.car(1, "red");
```

However,  I want to be able to declare a new car without using `carModel.car` and just use `car`

I'm using: `browserify`, `watchify`, `tsify`, `babel` in my Gulp build.

Comment: I think it should be `carModel.Car`

Answer (score 0):

I would try

```
class Car{
    constructor(
        public id: number,
        public color: string
    ){ }
}
exports = Car;
```

Take a look here: [module.exports in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696236/module-exports-in-typescript)

If you are just starting out maybe take a look at the es2015 import syntax which plays well with typescript.
[Typescript 1.8 - ES2015 imports in js files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35134618/typescript-1-8-es2015-imports-in-js-files)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Typescript doesn't seem to like the `exports`. The error is saying `is not a module.`

Answer (score 0):

how about

`import {Car} from '../models/CarModel.ts'`

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was creating a new class in the file I wanted to use the model. The new class would extend the model I imported.

```
import carModel = require('../models/CarModel.ts');
class Car extends carModel.Car{}
```

And now I can use `Car` as a type.